# Locating openssl on Debian

Tags: openssl, debian

I've installed the most recent Debian, and I'm trying to use OpenSSL:

```
root@debianvm:~# apt-get install openssl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openssl is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@debianvm:~# openssl
-su: openssl: command not found
```

`locate openssl` outputs enormous list, but I can't see the `openssl` executable there.

So, where is it?

**Update**:

`updatedb` doesn't seem to affect `locate openssl` output.

```
root@debianvm:~# uname -a
Linux debianvm 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.41-2+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@debianvm:~# which openssl
root@debianvm:~#
root@debianvm:~# dpkg -l | grep openssl
ii  libcurl4-openssl-dev                  7.26.0-1+wheezy2                   amd64        development files and documentation for libcurl (OpenSSL flavour)
ii  libgnutls-openssl27:amd64             2.12.20-7                          amd64        GNU TLS library - OpenSSL wrapper
ii  openssl                               20130602-1                         amd64        Package created with checkinstall 1.6.2
root@debianvm:~#
```

Answer (score 2):

- Which Debian version are you running?
- What does "dpkg -l | grep openssl" shows?
- Did you run an "updatedb" before "locate openssl"?
- What does "which openssl" shows?

**Update**
Strange version of openssl... Mine is this:

```
ii  openssl    1.0.1e-2     amd64    Secure Socket Layer (SSL) binary and related cryptographic tools
```

Try reinstalling it:

> apt-get --reinstall install openssl

Comment: Well, "remove" then "install" seem to solve the issue. The question is whether the rest of soft will keep functioning now...

Comment: I've seen now that you not installed the openssl paket by using apt. If your software is searching PATH it should work fine.